# Is there anyway to get the activities of IAM user when login?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have requirement , I want get IAM user activities logs when he login ?

is there any service for the same and if yes those services are chargeable ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about give them specific permissions so you know which kind of activities a user can do?

Comment: Yes, but assume IAM user who has entire Ec2 access that time I need know how many instances created and destroyed by him.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, [AWS CloudTrail](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/home?region=us-east-1#) saves all activity of the user(s) for 3 months and for request later than that, you can request them through support channel. Not sure about the charges for those though.